# My Rails app works in development and pushes to Heroku without error, but page does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

**Please help me. I noticed that this question has been asked a few times with no answer. I've tried the solutions that I've seen and there has been no resolution.**

I am learning ruby on rails from a book "Rails Crash Course: A No Nonsence Guide to Ruby on Rails".

My problem comes when I enter Heroku Open

The browser opens and I get the following message

The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

I have ran my logs

```
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187449+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187450+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187450+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187451+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187452+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187452+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187453+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187453+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187454+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187708+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187710+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187711+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187711+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187712+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187713+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187717+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187714+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187717+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187718+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187719+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187719+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187720+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187721+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187721+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187722+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
2017-12-03T19:48:51.187723+00:00 app[web.1]: [076125bd-21fe-447f-98e8-2036caa4a683] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
2017-12-03T20:03:43.644271+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-12-03T20:03:46.386095+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
2017-12-03T20:03:46.976688+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-12-03T20:03:49.186838+00:00 app[worker.1]: rake aborted!
2017-12-03T20:03:49.186858+00:00 app[worker.1]: Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work' (see --tasks)
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187090+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187091+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187091+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:27:in `run'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187092+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187093+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187092+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:360:in `exec'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187089+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187094+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:444:in `start'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187095+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187095+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187097+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187094+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:20:in `dispatch'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187099+00:00 app[worker.1]: (See full trace by running task with --trace)
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187096+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:121:in `with_friendly_errors'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187097+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/bin/bundle:3:in `load'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187096+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.187094+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.15.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
2017-12-03T20:03:49.337634+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2017-12-03T20:03:49.326887+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-12-03T20:06:51.940770+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=mightymixer.herokuapp.com request_id=cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce fwd="104.152.232.201" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=1902 protocol=https
2017-12-03T20:06:51.943218+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] Started GET "/" for 104.152.232.201 at 2017-12-03 20:06:51 +0000
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945172+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce]   
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945204+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant PostController):
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945237+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce]   
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945371+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945377+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945374+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945376+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945378+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945379+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:582:in `get'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945380+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:613:in `constantize'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945381+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:85:in `controller_class_for'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945381+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:78:in `controller_class'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945382+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `controller'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945383+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:29:in `serve'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945384+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945385+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `each'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945385+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:33:in `serve'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945388+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945386+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:834:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945391+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945389+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945390+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945392+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945393+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `block in call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945392+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945394+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `run_callbacks'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945395+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:24:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945396+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945397+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945395+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:59:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945398+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945398+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945410+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945411+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945412+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945412+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945413+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945414+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945415+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945417+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945417+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945418+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945419+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945420+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945420+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945422+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:438:in `process_client'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945421+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:624:in `handle_request'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945423+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/server.rb:302:in `block in run'
2017-12-03T20:06:51.945424+00:00 app[web.1]: [cf3559e7-f176-4ddd-848e-ae08dede69ce] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/puma-3.11.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Any help would be great!

Post Controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :author, :body)
    end
end
```

Comment: I've been coding everything on my own from the book so far. I tried to used the source code from the book and I still receive the same error. I think I'm going to try to use another book so I can keep moving forward.

Comment: Here: `Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work' (see --tasks)` Does that task exist?

Comment: Thank you... I think you want me to google this line of code.

Answer (score 1):

the error log is saying there's a problem in your post controller,

> ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant
>   PostController):

If you can update your question with your post controller, then it might be easy to get help or have a look at it yourself as you might be able to fix it

Comment: Thank You! I updated my post and I'm trying to find the error on my own. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: `PostController` vs `PostsController` it's just a typo - Check your controller name.